# No audio (Dummy output) with Ryzen 4500U on fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install

Tags: sound, 20.04, output

I cannot use my computer without audio. Have installed Ubuntu 20.04. In audio settings there's this "Dummy output" device, which means there is no device. How can I solve it?